# how to use order by in sql select query to sort complaint no in ascending order

Tags: sql-order-by

```
qry1 = "Select * from ser_complaint_master a,ser_complaint_status b,company_master c
        where a.complaint_no=b.complaint_no
        and a.allocation_code=c.co_code
        and c.co_br_code='" + Session["BRCODE"] + "'
        and a.Complaint_Date>='" + Frdat + "' and a.Complaint_Date<='" + Todat + "'
        and a.status in ('Completed')
        and a.complaint_type in('" + cmptype + "')";
```

How to use ORDER BY in select query if more than one tables are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `order by a.complaint_no` to the end of the query.